# Comparing times and acting accordingly

Tags: android

So I have a scenario:

Using `System.currentTimeMillis()` I get the initial start time of my application.  Then, when I open it at another time, I get the time again.  Both of these times are saved as a `long` variable.

What I need to do is compare these two times, convert this difference to hours (x 600,000), and for every hour that has passed, subtract 5 from another integer variable.  I can find the difference in time, convert it to hours, but I can't figure out to subtract 5 for every hour that has passed.  Any help or pseudo code would be GREATLY appreciated.

-Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for every hour we subtract 5, then after {x} hours we will have subtracted `5 * x`.

So work out how many hours have passed, multiply it by five, and there you go.